# StartsWithIgnoreCase - Gremlin Graph DB query

Tags: mongodb, gremlin, graphdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to get all the data from GraphDB which starts with certain characters along with ignore case. I am able to write a query that will return me the list which starts with some characters but I am not able to perform any ignore-case operation in that query.

Any help will be appreciated.

Current Query which I am using -

```
 g.V().hasLabel('Product').has('name', TextP.startingwith('Acc'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Gremlin does not provide the ability to do a case-insensitive search like you want.  You will need to normalize your `name` field (i.e. make it all lower case) prior to saving it to perform this sort of search using the `startingWith` predicate.